# Another AsyncTask task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the next simple question. I have an AsyncTask that connects my client to a server. For each task the server does I need another one AsyncTask class?

Let's say that I need a task to fill an array from the server, another to return an integer from the server and one to return an object from the server to the client, I need 3 AsyncTask classes, one for each of these tasks?

Comment: not if you do them all in the same task...

Comment: @tyczj the tasks I am talking about there aren't happening all in the same time.Some of them yes, but not all of them.

Comment: so then yes you need 3. why do you think your dont need 3?

Comment: @tyczj I am new to android programming and I just found out AsyncTask and I am not familiar with it. I wasn't sure if I got it right or not. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AsyncTask` is good when you don't need to present any information to your user. Something like saving data to the server, that nobody really cares when it finishes.

When you need something to be loaded for the screen, you'd be better off with `AsyncTaskLoader` class, that provides all the necessary callbacks.

Besides that, I'd create as many `AsyncTask`s as necessary. They are cheap, they make the work done. Why worry?

Comment: I would say that the first statement describes rather a `Service` purpose. `AsyncTask` is for doing something shortly and present the result to the user.

Comment: @DoctororDrive please read the google docs to see why `AsyncLoader` was born and what are limitations of `AsyncTask`

Comment: @lenik man sorry for hijaking your answer but I have an question. AsyncTaskLoader can be used only once per object like AsyncTask?

Comment: @Akumu `AsyncTaskLoader` has members `onStartLoading()`, `onStopLoading()` and `onReset()`. I suppose you may reset and restart the loading if necessary. here's a [nice article](http://andreas-kluck.blogspot.jp/2012/02/asynctask-and-asynctaskloader.html) and a [Google documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) regarding `AsyncTaskLoader`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do 
1) you can call your 1 st async task from class A and add an interface to that asynctask which has one method like onfirstTaskCompleted()
2) call onfirstTaskCompleted() method in onPostExecute of your asyncTask 
3) in class A implement onfirstTaskCompleted() and start an new Async task from there.

and repeat the same steps to 2nd and also third async task

Answer (score 0):

You need `AsyncTask` whenever you want to do an operation asynchronously. 
You do the asynchronous part in the `doInBackground()` of your `AsyncTask`.
If you can do everything inside a single doInBackground then you need just one `AsyncTask`.
Such as connect, get data, disconnect.

If you must do 2 separate asynchronous operations then 2 `AsyncTasks`. Such as connect, get data in one task. Then present them to the user. Then send request to server to delete some data, say, selected the data selected by the user, this you do in another `AsyncTask`. Or you can use the same asynctask somehow have a different flow of execution in `doInBackground` for different scenarios.